# VBA Call a Variable Range

Tags: vba

I am trying to calculate a moving average (i.e. the average of B2:b4, b3:b5, etc.) but I cannot figure out how to call a variable range. How do I do tihs?

```
Sub SMA()
Dim SMA As Double

For Each cell In Range("b2:b8")

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Average(cell.Value, b5).Value

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You say "My issue" and "running into an issue", but you never actually explain what the issue is you're having, and don't ask a question at all. Please [edit] your post to both explain the problem and ask a specific question so we can try and help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:  ?

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("b2:b8").Cells
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Average(cell.Resize(3))
Next
```

However, you could insert this as a formula once and copy it down without VBA.

Comment: @KenuSemau this works great, thanks so much! And I'm trying to learn how to do various things in VBA, and I was struggling with that.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please 'accept' the answer. I get some points and others see that the question has been solved.